# jQuery can't change html using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit

I am trying to change the html in a page with jQuery. While it works in Firefox, it won't in chrome. What can I do to fix this?

Eg.

```
$('#test').html(<p>hi</p>);
```

will change the text fine, but if I had other html in the file and am overriding it with this, the old text is still displayed in chrome. Could this be a caching issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ,

```
$('#test').html("<p>hi</p>"); //.html() accepts quoted [.html("value")] value.
```

I think you want to appen to `#test` ,so use `.append()` instead of `.html()`.

And if want to overwrite the contents use `.html()`.

```
$('#test').html("<p>hi</p>");   //will override content of test.
$('#test').append("<p>hi</p>");   //will append <p>hi</p> to test.
```

Some thing interesting for you,

```
$('#test').html(value) is equivalent to $('#test').empty().append(value).
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the quotes.

```
$('#test').html("<p>hi</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

`html()` accepts a string. So you need to encapsulate those characters in quotes.

`$('#test').html("<p>hi</p>");`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace text of your id #test then use

```
$('#test').html("<p>hi</p>");
```

wanna append more add `<p>hi</p>` tag in test id use

```
$('#test').append("<p>hi</p>");
```